# Mind boggling javascript failure at handling some basic addition!

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is killing me! I'm trying to add the values of four fields together, and I get allllll kinds of wierd results!

**The code I have so far:**

```
$('input.percent').change(function() {
    var totalup = 1;
    var totalup = totalup*1;
    $('input.percent').each(function(){
        var current = $(this).val();
        var curvalue = current * 1;
        console.log(curvalue);
        console.log(totalup);
        var totalup = curvalue + totalup;
    });
});
```

This should be ungodly simply. Start with a value of zero, get the value of each input, add it to that totaling value. The console log always shows UNDECLARED or NaN for totalup, but if I remove the last decleration of totalup (where it adds more to totalup) it suddenly doesn't become undefined or Nan.

Why is this not ungodly simply!!! I must be missing something dumb, or Javascript just STINKS!

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var percentInputs = $('input.percent');
percentInputs.change(function() {
     var total = 0;
     percentInputs.each(function(){
         total += Number($(this).val());
     });
});
```

#### Update

Caching those selectors would be a good idea too.

Comment: God darnit, your solution is so simple. I still don't get why what I had above wasn't working. Commenting out the "var totalup = curvalue + totalup;" resulted in totalup being fine, however leaving it alive resulted in totalup ='ing "UNDECLARED" in the console log, which is odd as the console log should come before the totalup second iteration is called... argh!@!!!

Comment: Oh duh... the issue relates to global vs local variable declarations.

Answer (score 2):

the main problem is the declaration of already declared fields. Leaf the `var` keyword for the second and third assignment of `totalup` and it'll work.

Answer (score 0):

add the `parseInt()` while the calculation for an example

```
 var totalup = parseInt(curvalue) + parseInt(totalup);
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay! Here is where the issue was arising!!!!

**When you write:**

```
var FOO = 'whatever';
```

...Inside of a function, it is a LOCAL VARIABLE! If however you simply go:

```
FOO = 'whatever';
```

You hit the global variable (variable declared outside of the function).

So while the code above is the solution, this is where the explained solution to the problem exists!

Comment: Sorry for being picky, but you do not necessarily write a global variable with the statement `FOO = '...'`. You write to a variable from the current frame/scope. Each function knows its own scope and the scope parent. So `FOO` is actually searched in the scope chain, which can end in the global scope.